# epoch timestamp to country local TZD format

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, dst, country-codes

I have epoch timestamp and country. I want convert that timestamp into given country local timestamp with time zone region with Daylight Saving (TZD) format as below

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:MM:ssTZD
e.g. 2018-02-25T22:36:23+0100

Timestamp : 1525370235
Country : NLD (ISO alpha-3 code)
```

How I can achieve this in Java?

**Update 1** :

I am using this kind of conversion but not sure is it correct or wrong. Can somebody let me know is this the corect way to do conversion

```
Locale locale = new Locale("NLD");
Date date = new Date(1525381190 * 1000L);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatCN = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ", locale);

 //Output : 2018-05-03T01:59:50-0700
```

Comment: Please, provide example of timestamp and country.

Comment: Please see my updated question with timestamp and Country Code.

Comment: In case anyone else was wondering, according to https://laendercode.net/en/3-letter-code/nld NLD is for Netherlands.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this the corect way to do conversion

No it is not. I see the following issues.

- The whole thing is impossible because many countries span several time zones. This means, from a country code you cannot know which time zone to choose. Since the local time varies by time zone, you cannot print the correct time in these cases. Countries that span more than one time zone include but are not limited to Canada, USA, Mexico, Greenland, Brazil, Ecuador, Russia, Indonesia, Kiribati — and even the Netherlands, your example country. Note that some of the countries with the largest populations are in the list, so if your data are representative of the world population you may more often than not encounter this problem. Please see [this list: List of time zones by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_country).
- Locale and time zone are two different things and though both more or less tied to places in no way directly related. So obtaining the correct locale will not help you. You can also see that your printed output has UTC offset -0700, where the correct offset for Amsterdam in summer would have been +0200.
- `new Locale("NLD")` will not give you a valid locale for the Netherlands. The argument to the `Locale(String)` constructor is a language tag like `nl` for Dutch or `en` for English. A three-letter country code will not work.
- Therefore, if you wanted to do just some of the work you are asking about, you would need access to some database or databases that can convert country code to country and country to time zones. I don’t know of a good choice here, but I would expect that some such databases are available.

### java.time

Finally, don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are long outdated and poorly designed. The modern correct way to format your epoch timestamp value for mainland Netherlands is:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam");
    String nldTime = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1_525_370_235L)
            .atZone(zone)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(nldTime);
```

This prints:

> 2018-05-03T19:57:15+02:00

If you need the offset without colon as in `+0200`, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX")`.

If instead of Amsterdam you wanted the time in the Caribbean municipalities of the Netherlands, use America/Kralendijk time zone. Then the result is `2018-05-03T13:57:15-04:00`.

Comment: Thanks Ole V.V for this detail answer. I will think on your solution but my problem is country is not fix here. It will change on each server request.

Answer (score -1):

There no actual Oracle time zone in the iso format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3.

So, I would like to suggest to you to make a mapping between ISO zones and Oracle timezones https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-display-list-of-timezone-with-gmt/

So, my solution to your question looks like:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class IsoToOracleDate {

static Map<String, String> timezones = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
   put("NLD","Europe/Amsterdam");
   put("RUS","Europe/Moscow");
   put("USA","America/New_York");
}};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String zone = timezones.get("NLD");
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(zone);
    long epochMilli = 1525370235 * 1000L;
    LocalDateTime dt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli).atZone(zoneId).toLocalDateTime();
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(dt, zoneId);
    System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
}
}
```

Outputs:

> 2018-05-03T19:57:15+02:00

You have timezones mapping in the **timezones** variable.

Create ZoneId(oracle) from mapping **ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(zone);**

Create LocalDateTime **dt** from **epochMilli** according to your zone and convert it to the ZonedDateTime **zdt**.

Then just format **zdt** with predefined format DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME

Comment: USA != New York.  Russia is even wider and has many more time zones.  Such mappings are impossible.

Comment: Please, read the whole answer. I'm writing "So, I would like to suggest to you to make a mapping between ISO zones and Oracle timezones ". I suggest to choose one city(may be capital city, or New Your for USA) for the big countries and make a mapping between ISO zones and Oracle time zones. So, such mapping is possible if you make an assumption to choose one city in the country.

Comment: How is that useful for residents of Hawaii, for example?  (6 hours difference from New York)

Comment: @MattJohnson Please, Matt, be attentive to the question "Country : NLD (ISO alpha-3 code)". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3 doesn't have Hawaii, only countries. That's why I suggest to make a one-to-one mapping.

Comment: Hawaii is a US state. My point is that both Hawaii and New York have the country code USA, but they have drastically different time zones. Saying "pick one" is not useful. The downvote thus is warranted, as your answer is not useful.

Comment: It is only your opinion. It is obvious that Vladivostok has 7 hours difference with Moscow! It was my suggestion to the described problem. It is very strange that you downvote if opinion doesn't equal to my. Saying "pick one" is useful, because I see that it is the only one solution. The actual problem is that @pbb should deal only with Main country time zone as described here for example: https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2009/sep/14/time-zones-countries-world-gmt .